# Hypergeometric probability question for Magic the Gathering (a card game)

Tags: probability

So I have a somewhat complicated situation that I'm not particularly sure how to handle, so I thought I'd ask here. The situation is as follows:

I have a 60 card deck. I play 4 copies of card A, 4 copies of card B, 4 copies of card C, and X copies of card D. Card D has a special interaction where it is capable of finding any of card A, B, or C. What are the odds of me finding at least one of each of cards A, B, and C having drawn n cards?

For simplicity sake, let us assume that card D will always find the card I do not have, and that it will not find one until I am only missing one.

Comment: It's a little hard to parse out your Question, so let me try and say what I think is the combinatorial problem.  The cards in the deck consist of $A,B,C,D$ and some other "do not care" cards.  You will draw $n$ out of the $60$ cards, and you will "succeed" if these contain any three of the four kinds of cards $A,B,C,D$ (since a $D$ will "find" the missing card for you, if necessary).  So it might be an "inclusion/exclusion" counting exercise.

Comment: That sounds about right. You don't need to have exactly one copy from three of the four kinds, just at least one. I've typically used hypergeometric to do the calculations when considering only one kind of card, but I can tell this is slightly different.

Comment: My explanation of how to count the "failure" cases by inclusion/exclusion was confused.  Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything other than "inclusion/exclusion" counting that tells me how I should solve it, so I'm still confused how to obtain the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break down the possible cases for "failure" into:

- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $A$ and $B$
- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $A$ and $C$
- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $A$ and $D$
- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $B$ and $C$
- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $B$ and $D$
- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $C$ and $D$

Each of these cases can be counted by simple application of binomial coefficients.  E.g. the ways that $n$ cards may be drawn without getting either $A$ or $B$ cards is:

$$ \text{# of ways to draw missing A and B} = \binom{52}{n} $$

since after omitting the $A$ and $B$ cards, the $n$ cards will be chosen from the remaining $52$ card deck.

**NB:** Corrected thanks to Michael Yousef's observation of missing case $A,C,D$

Summing up all six cases will "cover" all the possible ways to fail, but there is some overcounting when we do so.  Cases where three kinds of cards are missing will be included in the above sum more than once:

- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $A$, $B$, and $C$
- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $A$, $B$, and $D$
- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $A$, $C$, and $D$
- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $B$, $C$, and $D$

For example, the outcomes where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all missing gets counted three times in our original breakdown of six cases (when $A,B$ are missing, when $A,C$ are missing, and again when $B,C$ are missing).  To fix this we subtract twice the sum of these "three missing kind" cases from the sum of the original six "two missing kind" cases.

There is one final correction to get the exact count of "failure" outcomes.  The case of all four kinds missing:

- the $n$ cards drawn are missing $A,B,C,D$

was counted once in each of the original six cases (so plus six times), but then subtracted twice for each of the next four cases (so minus eight times).  The result is that these got undercounted in the corrected count so far, and we need to add them back three times ($6-8+3 = 1$) to get the final exact count of "failure" cases.

The count of successes is simply the subtraction of the count of failures from the universe of $n$ cards drawn from a deck of $60$, i.e.

$$ \text{# of ways to succeed} = \binom{60}{n} - (\text{# of ways to fail}) $$

These absolute counts can be converted to probabilities by dividing by the universal count, $\binom{60}{n}$, if so desired.  However if the purpose is to judge the effectiveness of varying the count $X$ of cards of type $D$, this analysis can be done from comparing the counts.

Comment: Looks pretty good, and I could get the answer out of it. You missed the case for 3 missing of A, C, and D, so I had to calculate that as well, and this caused me to have to fix the final case of A, B, C, D as well, but it wasn't that bad.

Comment: Excellent!  I will edit accordingly.